# HTTP status 500 for wso2 carbon application

Tags: java, wso2

I tried [this tutorial](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2012/12/providing-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-webapps/) and after entering with admin as in step 8, I got the error as follows:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Exception while making the decision : org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused: connect
org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.filter.exception.EntitlementFilterException: Exception while making the decision : org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused: connect
org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.filter.EntitlementFilter.doFilter(EntitlementFilter.java:191)
```

Answer (score 0):

1)
Is your WSO2 Server running against loclahost only or is it just running on his IP adres? Looks like you are not able to contact the server through this IP and/or port number.

2)
Are there any proxies defined? If so, try to disable them.

Comment: pls,My IS server version is wso2is-4.5.0 (https://localhost:9445/carbon) and AS is wso2as-5.1.0 (https://localhost:9443/carbon).
I got error for "http://127.0.0.1:9763/Entitlement_Sample_WebApp/protected.jsp".I tried with network settings both "No Proxy" and "Auto-detect proxy..". Also tried with "Manual proxy configuration" and "No Proxy for:" with "localhost, 127.0.0.1:9763,127.0.0.1:9443,127.0.0.1:9445". But not ok. Local Area Connection properties is (TCP/IPv4) "Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server automatically".

Comment: Did you have the loopback adapter installed under windows?

Comment: sure! now I got it. I don't know how to change the web app service to go to IS server(localhost:9445). so I changed port for IS server as 9444. now it's work well. thks all!